# How to Store Text in Different Locales

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Currently, I am developing a multilingual form where users can enter information about companies in both English and Arabic (Other languages may be supported later).

I have string variables like `companyNameEn` to store the English name of the company and `companyNameAr` to store its Arabic name and so on. These names will be stored in a database once the user clicks a save `Button`. I feel like this is not the proper way of storing the texts for different languages as similar variables will be declared for each language by adding the language code (En, Ar, Rr...) as suffix. I believe this way makes adding a new language later a hard thing to do and makes the system hard to maintain.

I thought of defining variables of type `Dictionary` for each user-keyed data where I set a language code and then assign the language text as shown below:

```
`Dim companyName As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
`companyName.Add("en", "Company name")`
`companyName.Add("ar", "اسم الشركة")`
```

I am not sure of whether this is a correct way of handling data of different languages as I need a `Dictionary` variable for each data.

Comment: How about a `Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))` where the outer dictionary is for the language?

Comment: This is not a good way of doing it. If I would use `Dictionary(Of String, String)` then there is no need for the outer language code dictionary. I mean the idea of `Dictionary(Of String, String)` is similar to using a variable for each language data which I am to avoid

Comment: If you're storing the data in a database then you should use separate tables.  You'd have a Company table, a Locale table and then a CompanyName table, which would have a CompanyId foreign key to Company and a LocaleId foreign key to Locale.  Each company can then have zero, one or more names, each for a different locale.  Your `Company` entity would then have a `Names` property that was a collection of names and their locales.  You would probably want to also record which was the default name.

Comment: @jmcilhinney what you have suggested is exactly what I am using. Yes, I have those tables already. My question is not regarding the implementation of the database but regarding the user interface application which takes the names as user entry.

Comment: _(Responding to second comment):_ But you need to store it somewhere and you need separate entries for every language and language object. A `Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))` would do what you need and it keeps everything in one variable: `languages("en")("companyName")`. There is no way to _avoid_ having one entry per language and one entry per object, no matter what solution you use.

Comment: I'm not sure why the entity structure wouldn't mirror the database structure.